# why is "arp -a" showing inconsistent outputs that are vastly different?

Tags: arp

I have newly set up a computer with Ubuntu 18.04 and connected to my home wifi. When I try `arp -a` command to scan other devices connected to the same network, I see some very weird outputs.

First, the connect is fine by checking `ifconfig`:

```
john@home:~$ ifconfig 
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 246054  bytes 21958490 (21.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 246054  bytes 21958490 (21.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e3f:e0a5:2438:a96a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 240d:1a:6a5:c900:1420:b3cc:994b:1b7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 240d:1a:6a5:c900:74f4:f504:3a41:bc12  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 04:33:c2:c4:02:a2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2452125  bytes 3302288691 (3.3 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 964749  bytes 117659686 (117.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It has the ip address of 192.168.1.14
Then I tried `arp -a`:

```
john@home:~$ arp -a 
? (192.168.1.19) at 92:c4:78:3c:46:16 [ether] on wlo1
_gateway (192.168.1.1) at e4:7e:66:1f:bf:4c [ether] on wlo1
? (192.168.1.5) at 26:36:46:f9:69:83 [ether] on wlo1
```

which makes sense because I can confirm that my ipad has ip address of `192.168.1.19` and my phone has ip address of `192.168.1.5`

However, after a while I executed `arp -a` again, and the output blows my mind:

```
john@home:~$ arp -a 
? (192.168.1.206) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.183) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.107) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.8) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.18) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.165) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.186) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.110) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.77) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.33) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.178) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.123) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.112) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.96) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.117) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.74) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.95) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.84) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.41) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.62) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.51) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.8) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.29) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.18) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.231) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.252) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.241) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.198) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.219) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.208) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.165) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.186) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.143) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.132) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.153) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.110) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.99) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.120) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.77) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.66) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.87) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.44) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.33) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.54) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.11) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.21) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.234) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.244) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.201) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.222) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.211) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.168) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.189) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.178) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.135) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.156) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.145) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.102) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.123) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.112) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.69) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.90) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.47) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.36) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.57) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.3) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.24) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.237) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.226) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.247) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.204) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.193) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.214) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.171) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.160) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.181) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.138) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.159) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.148) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.105) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.126) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.115) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.72) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.93) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.82) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.39) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.60) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.49) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.6) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.27) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.16) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.229) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.250) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.207) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.196) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.217) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.174) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.163) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.184) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.141) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.130) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.151) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.108) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.97) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.118) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.75) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.64) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.85) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.42) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.63) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.52) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.9) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.30) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.19) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.232) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.253) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.242) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.199) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.220) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.209) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.166) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.187) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.176) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.133) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.154) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.111) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.100) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.121) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.78) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.67) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.88) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.45) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.34) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.55) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.12) at <incomplete> on wlo1
_gateway (192.168.1.1) at e4:7e:66:1f:bf:4c [ether] on wlo1
? (192.168.1.22) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.235) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.224) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.245) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.202) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.223) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.212) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.169) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.190) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.179) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.136) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.157) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.146) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.103) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.124) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.113) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.70) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.91) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.80) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.37) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.58) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.15) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.4) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.25) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.238) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.227) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.248) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.205) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.194) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.215) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.172) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.161) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.182) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.139) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.128) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.149) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.106) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.127) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.116) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.73) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.94) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.83) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.40) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.61) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.50) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.7) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.28) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.17) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.230) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.251) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.240) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.197) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.218) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.175) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.164) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.185) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.142) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.131) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.152) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.109) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.98) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.119) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.76) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.65) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.86) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.43) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.32) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.53) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.10) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.31) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.20) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.233) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.254) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.243) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.200) at <incomplete> on wlo1
? (192.168.1.221) at <incomplete> on wlo1
john@home:~$
```

What is this?  What just happened?
I thought `arp -a` is supposed to scan and list other devices on the same network. What are these results?

Answer (score 1):

**arp -a** does not actively scan, it merely shows what the ARP table contains at the moment.
The ARP table contains translations of known IP to MAC address translations.
An entry becomes known once a communication with an IP needs to be translated to MAC the first time. It is resolved via ARP protocol and stored in the ARP table.

The situation you see in the ARP means there have been some communication attempt with a specific IP address. However if you see incomplete, that means the IP was not successfuly resolved to a MAC.

It may suggest something was scanning IP addresses in your range but was mostly not successful.

see more here: https://www.dummies.com/programming/networking/network-administration-arp-command/

However the fact, that something is scanning may be a sign of some malicious code running on your computer.